# Java threaded for loop with pause and resume

Tags: java, loops

let say i have a for loop of 1000 and it do some stuff. I can inside a pause function with a button 'pause' and unpause with a button 'resume'.

Question do i need to implement a thread for such a case?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Do stuff
pause();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the answer is No, you don't need to implement an additional thread. If you follow the usual pattern for GUI programs, this thread will be running in a thread different from the main GUI thread anyway, and that is sufficient.

You will need to check in each iteration of the for loop that the user paused the system and wait for the resume. This can be done with a simple notify signal pattern. [For instance](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `boolean` flag:

```
public volatile boolean paused = false;
public final int littleTime = 100; //ms

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    // Do stuff
    pause();
}

public void pause() {
    paused = true;
    while (paused)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(littleTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

public void resume() {
    paused = false;
}
```

Comment: while paused generate as many `NOOPS` as the cpu is capable of?

Comment: You may add something like `Thread.sleep(100);` to improve efficience

Comment: This is a common anti-pattern ;) Users will stone you if you try that on a mobile app

Comment: any reason for a sleep

Comment: the one Tedil mentioned

Comment: i just tested this code but it doesnt stop on action perform, however it only stop at the next time it start

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean to state if it is *Paused*

```
volatile boolean isPause = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Do stuff if not passed
    if(!isPause)
    doStuff();
}
```

Note : Set the `isPause` flag to `true` when you hit `Pause` button. Reset the `isPause` flag to false when you hit `Resume` button. I have also marked `boolean` as `volatile` so that the variable is always read from main memory (no cache) since both read and write are atomic in this case

Comment: I think zou have to use volatile on the bool. Also, this trashes cycles like crazy :)

Comment: @mafu ha ha, KISS ;) Corrected, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a thread because this loop you're showing has to be run in a worker thread, while the button and the code processing the button press event has to be run in the GUI thread. So from the GUI thread you want to pause your worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

This implements a pauseable thread. See the comments at the top on how to use it. See examples of usage in the `main` method.

```
/**
 * PauseableThread is a Thread with pause/resume and cancel methods.
 *
 * The meat of the process must implement `step`.
 *
 * You can either extend this and implement `step` or use the factory.
 *
 * I cannot extend Thread because my resume will clash.
 *
 */
public abstract class PauseableThread implements Runnable {

    // The lock.

    private final ReadWriteLock pause = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = pause.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = pause.writeLock();
    // Flag to cancel the wholeprocess.
    private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
    // The exception that cause it to finish.
    private Exception thrown = null;
    // The thread that is me.
    private Thread me = null;

    @Override
    // The core run mechanism.
    public void run() {
        // Track my current thread.
        me = Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            while (!finished()) {
                // Block here if we're paused.
                blockIfPaused();
                // Don't do any more work if we've been asked to stop.
                if (!finished()) {
                    // Do my work.
                    step();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Just fall out when exception is thrown.
            thrown = ex;
        }
    }

    // Have we finished yet?
    private boolean finished() {
        return cancelled || !me.isInterrupted();
    }

    // Block if pause has been called without a matching resume.
    private void blockIfPaused() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            // Grab a write lock. Will block if a read lock has been taken.
            writeLock.lockInterruptibly();
        } finally {
            // Release the lock immediately to avoid blocking when pause is called.
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Pause the work. NB: MUST be balanced by a resume.
    public void pause() {
        // We can wait for a lock here.
        readLock.lock();
    }

    // Resume the work. NB: MUST be balanced by a pause.
    public void resume() {
        // Release the lock.
        readLock.unlock();
    }

    // Stop.
    public void cancel() {
        // Stop everything.
        cancelled = true;
    }

    // Stop immediately (if param is true).
    public void cancel(boolean interrupt) {
        if (interrupt) {
            // Interrupt me.
            me.interrupt();
        } else {
            // Or cancel me.
            cancel();
        }
    }

    // Wait for completion.
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        // Wait 'till we've finished. NB: Will wait forever if you haven't instigated a cancel of some kind.
        while (me.isAlive()) {
            Thread.sleep(0);
        }
    }

    // Start - like a thread.
    public void start() {
        // Wrap me in a thread and fire the sucker up!
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    // Get the exception that was thrown to stop the thread or null if the thread was cancelled.
    public Exception getThrown() {
        return thrown;
    }

    // Expose my Thread.
    public Thread getThread() {
        return me;
    }

      // Create this method to do stuff.
    // Calls to this method will stop when pause is called.
    // Any thrown exception stops the whole process.
    public abstract void step() throws Exception;

    // Factory to wrap a Stepper in a PauseableThread
    public static PauseableThread make(Stepper stepper) {
        StepperThread pauseableStepper = new StepperThread(stepper);
        // That's the thread they can pause/resume.
        return pauseableStepper;
    }

    // One of these must be used.
    public interface Stepper {

        // A Stepper has a step method.
        // Any exception thrown causes the enclosing thread to stop.

        public void step() throws Exception;
    }

    // Holder for a Stepper.
    private static class StepperThread extends PauseableThread {

        // The actual stepper I am proxying.

        private final Stepper stepper;

        StepperThread(Stepper stepper) {
            this.stepper = stepper;
        }

        @Override
        public void step() throws Exception {
            stepper.step();
        }
    }

      // !!!! Testing only below !!!!
    // My test counter.
    static int n = 0;

    // Test/demo.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            // Simple stepper that just increments n.
            Stepper s = new Stepper() {
              @Override
              public void step() throws Exception {
                n += 1;
                Thread.sleep(1);
              }
            };
            PauseableThread pt = PauseableThread.make(s);
            // Start it up.
            pt.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pt.pause();
            System.out.println("Paused: " + n);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Resuminng: " + n);
            pt.resume();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pt.cancel();
            System.out.println("Finished: " + n);

            // Start again to test agressive cancelling.
            pt.await();
            n = 0;
            pt = PauseableThread.make(s);
            // Start it up.
            pt.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pt.pause();
            System.out.println("Paused: " + n);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Resuminng: " + n);
            pt.resume();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // Cancel aggressively.
            pt.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Finished: " + n);
            System.out.println("thrown: " + pt.getThrown());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: such a long piece of code? where did u cut it from?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer - My own private stash. :) If you plan to do something often you had better do it right. This is my *right way*. It moves all of the complex edge cases away and makes pausing threads simple. No spinlocks! No wait/notify! No `Thread.sleep()` (except in the testing and where absolutely necessary)! Retains the exception that caused it to stop!

Comment: thanks bro, i might need time to understand this...pretty new to threading as i just took up java in college